# Accordion +/- content string markers not working

Tags: javascript

Found a javascript accordion example that was 90% of what I wanted (open a main accordion based on href) and modified it to basically add one level of sub accordion with right side "more info +" and "less info -" content markers that only open and close by explicit click (no auto closing across accordions).

Usage will have multiple sub accordions in parallel but no further sub nesting. While the text within the various accordions opens and closes properly, the accordion content markers are not acting as expected.

For a single sub accordion, a click open switches marker to "less -" and section displays, but on click close action the section closes but marker doesn't switch back to original "more info +" state. When multiple sub accordions then open works as above and a click close of a particular sub accordion closes the accordion, however, the marker stays in "less info -" state (as above) and text closes, but first above accordion that is in open "less info -" state switches just the marker to "more info +" state (data stays open).

The sub accordions needed to operate independent of each other and the markers to properly toggle but I don't understand what I'm missing.

As I'll only ever have 3-4 max parallel sub accordions, I did experiment with creating numbered duplicate sub accordions so they would be independent and while this was a hack way to solved the "cross accordion leakage". So I can live with that hack if I can just get the markers working properly.

My code ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        // Hide all panels
        $(".subpanel").hide(); 
        // Show first panel by default
        $(".mainaccordion:eq(0)").next(".subpanel").show();
        $(".mainaccordion:first").addClass("active");
        // Get hash from query string
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if (hash) {
            // Get panel header element
            var requestedPanel = $(hash);
            if (requestedPanel.length) {
                // Hide all panels
                $(".subpanel").hide();
                $('.mainaccordion').removeClass("active"); // remove active
                // Show requested panel
                requestedPanel.next(".subpanel").show();
                requestedPanel.addClass("active"); //add active
            }
        };

        $('body').find('.mainaccordion').click(function() {
            //Expand or collapse this panel
            $(this).next().slideToggle('300');
            $('.mainaccordion').removeClass("active"); // remove active
            $(this).addClass("active"); // add active
            //Hide the other panels
            $(".subpanel").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
        });
        $('body').find('.subpanelaccordion').click(function() {
            //Expand or collapse this panel
            $(this).next().slideToggle('300');
            $('.subpanelaccordion').removeClass("active"); // remove active
            $(this).addClass("active"); // add active
        });
        $('body').find('.subpanelaccordion1').click(function() {
            //Expand or collapse this panel
            $(this).next().slideToggle('300');
            $('.subpanelaccordion1').removeClass("active"); // remove active
            $(this).addClass("active"); // add active
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
  .mainaccordion {margin-left: 20px; cursor: pointer;}
  .subpanelaccordion { cursor: pointer;}
  .subpanelaccordion:after        { cursor: pointer; margin-left: 24px; color: #0000FF ; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; content: "(more info \02795 )";}
  .subpanelaccordion.active:after { content: "(less info \2796 )";}
  .subpanel {margin-left: 40px; display: none;}
  .subpanelsubpanel {display: none;}
  .mainaccordion.active + .accordion-content { display: block; }
  .subpanelaccordion.active + .accordion-content { display: block; }
  .smallbold {font-weight:bold;font-size:85%}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
  <h4 class="mainaccordion" id="q1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis</h4>
  <div class="subpanel"><p>Select chapter to view.</p></div>

  <h4 class="mainaccordion" id="AAAA">Chapter AAAA</h4>
  <div class="subpanel"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis. <a href="#BBBB" onclick="setTimeout('history.go(0);',300);">Open BBBB.</a></p></div>

  <h4 class="mainaccordion" id="BBBB">Chapter BBBB</h4>
  <div class="subpanel"><p >Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.
        <div class="subpanelaccordion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis: item 1.</div>
        <div class="subpanelsubpanel"><ul>
              <li><span class=smallbold>For a1,</span> the value is foo.</li>
              <li><span class=smallbold>For a2,</span> the value is foo.</li>
              </ul></div> 
              <p></p>
        <div class="subpanelaccordion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis: item 2.</div>
        <div class="subpanelsubpanel"><ul>
              <li><span class=smallbold>For a1,</span> the value is foo.</li>
              <li><span class=smallbold>For a2,</span> the value is foo.</li>
              </ul></div> 
              <p></p>
        <div class="subpanelaccordion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis: item 3.</div>
        <div class="subpanelsubpanel"><ul>
              <li><span class=smallbold>For a1,</span> the value is foo.</li>
              <li><span class=smallbold>For a2,</span> the value is foo.</li>
              </ul></div> 
    </p>
  </div>

  <h4 class="mainaccordion" id="DDDD">Chapter DDDD</h4>
  <div class="subpanel"><p class=margin40>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p></div>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try for this:
This is the second accordian that you want to make it up,

```
$('body').find('.subpanelaccordion').click(function() {
            //Expand or collapse this panel
            $(this).next().slideToggle('300');
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){  //Here we check if elemnet has active class already the remove it otherwise add to it.
                $(this).removeClass("active");
             // remove active
            }
            else{
            $(this).addClass("active"); // add active
            }
        });
```

Comment: Here we have check, if element has already active class then remove it otherwise add active class to current selection of the element

Comment: That did the trick on open/close marker and no "cross accordion leakage"... thank you so much.